# document.addEventListener not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a chrome extension which simply alerts "Foo" whenever a new DOM node is inserted during a page load. The following code does not work:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "2.0",
  "manifest_version": 1,
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
"content_scripts": [
 {
  "run_at": "document_start",
  "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
  "js": ["test.js"]
 }]
}
```

test.js:

```
function nodeInsertedCallback(event) {
  alert("Foo");
});
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', nodeInsertedCallback);
```

When test.js is simply:

```
alert("Foo");
```

The alert is shown, indicating it's not an issue with the manifest or with the extension itself.

Comment: Your `test.js` code as written here has a syntax error (unnecessary closing parenthesis on the third line). If you remove that parenthesis, does the code work? Did you check your console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error on the third line. But I also suggest wrapping your code into an [IFFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Giving you an end result like:

```
(function() {
  function nodeInsertedCallback(event) {
    alert("Foo");
  });
  document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', nodeInsertedCallback);
}).call(this)
```